# Twitter in_reply_to_status_id signature

Tags: javascript, twitter, cryptojs, servicenow

I am working on twitter integration. I am using CryptoJs to create a signature. Here is the code.

The issue is, following code is working without "in_reply_to_status_id" parameter, but with that parameter it is giving "could not authenticate issue".

```
var autSign =
        'oauth_consumer_key=' + percentEncode(consumer_key) + '&' +
        'oauth_nonce=' + percentEncode(nonce) + '&' +
        'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&' +
        'oauth_timestamp=' + timeStamp + '&' +
        'oauth_token=' + percentEncode(access_token) + '&' +
        'oauth_version=1.0&status=test3&in_reply_to_status_id=1217119832744898564';

var baseString =
    "POST&" +
    percentEncode(endpoint) + "&" + percentEncode(autSign);

var signingKey = this.percentEncode(consumer_secret) +
    "&" + this.percentEncode(access_token_secret);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(baseString, signingKey);
var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted);
```

Comment: Make sure to tag the language you're using, not just libraries, or the question is less likely to be seen

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Camille. I am using Javascript in Servicenow.

Comment: I have a similar challenge with getting authenticated to a different system using CryptoJS in SN. Did you import CryptoJS on your own into your instance?